# Redirecionamento de dados com mongodb

Tags: mongodb, nosql

Eu queria saber se é possível direcionar um objeto/resultado para uma coleção especifica usando o comando `db.collection.find()`, o que iria a equivaler o `$out` na operação de agregação.

Comment: O `db.collection.find()` serve apenas para buscar informações num documento. O que você poderia fazer seria declarar uma variável com o valor do find e então adicioná-lo à coleção com os métodos adequados.

Comment: Obrigado meu amigo :D

Comment: Isso respondeu a pergunta? funcionou?